# retrieve image from mongodb and display on client side

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

Now I'm using express, node.js, and mongodb. I just saw that the images can be stored to mongodb with multer and grid fs storage and it works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghCim.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT0pU.png)

And I need to get back to client side. I guess the image can be converted from that chunk binary to image but I really sure how to do so. My ultimate purpose is to display menu with name, price, and picture from mongodb which I uploaded.

Does anyone know how to retrieve it and send image file from controller to boundary class?

Additional resources:

```
//this is entity class which is for obtaining information about image file
static async getImages(menu) {
        try {
            let filter = Object.values(menu.image)
            const files = await this.files.find({ filename: { $in: filter } }).toArray()   
            let fileInfos = []
            
            for (const file of files) {
                let chunk = await this.chunks.find({ files_id: file._id }).toArray()
                console.log(chunk.data)
                fileInfos.push(chunk.data)
            }

            return fileInfos
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`Unable to get files: ${err.message}`)
        }
    }
```

** so chunk object contains this**

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("627a28cda6d7935899174cd4"),
    files_id: new ObjectId("627a28cda6d7935899174cd3"),
    n: 0,
    data: new Binary(Buffer.from("89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d49484452000000180000001808020000006f15aaaf0000000674524e530000000000006ea607910000009449444154789cad944b12c0200843a5e3fdaf9c2e3a636d093f95a586f004b5b5e30100c0b2f8daac6d1a25a144e4b74288325e5a23d6b6aea965b3e643e4243b2cc428f472908f35bb572dace8d4652e485bab83f4c84a0030b6347e3cb5cc28dbb84721ff23704c17a7661ad1ee96dc5f22ff5061f458e29621447e4ec8557ba585a99152b97bb4f5d5d68c92532b10f967bc015ce051246ff76d8b0000000049454e44ae426082", "hex"), 0)
  }
```

```
//this is controller class
static async apiViewMenu(_req, res) {
        try {
            let menus = await MenusDAO.getAllMenus()
            
            for (const menu of menus) {
                menu.images = await ImagesDAO.getImages(menu)
            }

            //return menus list
            res.json(menus)
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: err.message })
        }
    }
```

I did not handle converting this buffer data to image because I do not know...

Comment: There are at least 2 distinct questions in this question:  querying for an image in mongodb (likely using gridfs) and getting that image through the `node.js` machinery; then of course there is actually rendering it...   Please show what code you have tried.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I added few codes, I'm not sure it is enough or not.

Comment: I see `chunks` in the question; are you going thru the `gridfs` API or not?   I would hope to see the javascript gridfs API here.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti do you mean like gridfsbucket like that?

Comment: Exactly  -- we should see API calls as described in `https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/gridfs`.   Don't "manually" access the chunks.